# Как обвязать Espresso Android и Jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, espresso

Есть Espresso тесты Android и CI Jenkins, которая собирает проект.
Как реализовать запуск тестов после сборки проекта?

Comment: используете `pipelines` или `freestyle job`?

Comment: @FCh ```freestyle job```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно установить `qemu-kvm` и добавить Jenkins пользователя в эту группу. Собрать [Android Emulator Plugin](https://github.com/wbrunette/android-emulator-plugin). В Jenkins репозитории он слишком старый. И [JUnit Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit).

В вашей `Freestyle` джобе после перезагрузки Jenkins в `Build Environment` появится чекбокс `Run an Android emulator during build`. В `Execute Shell` вызовите команды для запуска тестов.

Подборка мануалов, с примерами того как это делать:

- Хороший [видео-пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U58yjkL6fRk), но здесь уже все предварительно установлено в Jenkins.
- [Пример с немного другой конфигурацией](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/08/11/a-step-by-step-tutorial-for-continuous-integration-with-jenkins-on-a-red-hat-mobile-native-android-application-part-2/), но шаги по конфигурированию такие же.
- [Пример для Headless Emulator и Espresso](https://www.winters.nz/running-android-espresso-tests-on-jenkins-with-headless-emulator/)

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Нужно проверить.